# Java, scan double only accepts int

Tags: java, int, double

Here's the part of code that isn't working properly, didn't want to paste all of it, it gives me "bad data" if i try to input 3.2 but works fine if I try for example 3. And all getters/setters ask for double, not int, debugger tells the same story, the moment i'd input 3.2 in would skin to printing bad data

```
double fastest = 1000;
double choice1timechoice;
boolean goodTime = false;
while(!(goodTime)) {
System.out.println("Enter time of the sprint:");

try {
    choice1timechoice = scan.nextDouble();
    if (choice1timechoice < fastest) {
    fastest = choice1timechoice;
    fastIndex = numSprints;
    }


    sprint[numSprints].setTime(fastest);

    goodTime = true;
    System.out.println("Do you wish to continue adding sprints? 1 for yes, 2 for no");
    cont = scan.nextInt();

    if (cont == 1) numSprints++;
  } 

catch (InputMismatchException ex)
  {
    System.out.println("Bad data");
    System.out.println("Please try again \n");
    scan.nextLine();
 }
}
```

Comment: You may not be handling end of line (EOL) tokens that need to be handled, leaving them dangling to be swallowed by the next call to `scan.nextLine()`. What happens if you place a `scan.nextLine()` after every call to `scan.nextInt()` or `scan.nextDouble()`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `Scanner`s skip whitespaces by default so I doubt that's the problem. I'm thinking that this might be a locale issue as `nextDouble()` uses the local decimal separator, which may not be `.`.

Comment: @T.C. No, Scanner's don't skip whitespace. Their default behavior is to use whitespace as a delimiter, however the EOL token is special, and will be swallowed as the delimiter for `Scanner#nextLine()`. I've seen errors with this behavior posted on this site time and again. However we will have to await the original poster's response to my comment before finding out if it is true.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How would I go around fixing that?

Comment: Btw, i tried putting scan.nextLine after every scan.nextDouble or scan.nextInt and it didn't help, it's still fine 3 but not for 3.2, and then when it takes in 3, it prints it as double aka 3.0

Comment: @user2627736: I don't see where you're printing out user input anywhere in your code posted above!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's not in the part of code i pasted, i didn't want the post to be too big because there are atm 276 lines of code in it, i tried to localize the problem

Comment: @user2627736: if we don't know what variable you're printing, how are we to guess what could be wrong? Please ask your questions from our point of view: Folks who have no idea what your problem is or code looks like unless you tell us and show us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, the documentation says that "The `next()` and `hasNext()` methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()`) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token."

Comment: @T.C.: you're correct, that my assumption is not part of the problem, but trust me, calling `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()` and then later getting String input from `nextLine()` will mess up due to non-handled EOL tokens. Experiment with it to see for yourself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it's all doubles, only int is in the very end of code where i ask for cont, besides printing has nothing to do with the exception being thrown out here

Comment: @user2627736: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user2627736: If you run `System.out.println(java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator());`, what's printed?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh yes, that would be messy, but it doesn't really apply in this case.

Comment: @T.C.: agree. Your suggestion above is probably correct.

Comment: @T.C. I just ran it and it printing out "," so i used 3,2 and it worked. That probably also explains why my code started having some bugs when i switched from mac to windows, once again thx

Comment: Its working fine for me. No errors or exceptions at all

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a locale issue. Based on the comments, the default local decimal separator on OP's system is `','` rather than `'.'`. Thus `Scanner` by default refuses to recognize `3.2` and only recognizes `3,2`.

To make the `Scanner` accept `3.2`, you can manually set its locale:

```
scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: well played. 1+ to you!

Answer (score 0):

As Hovercraft Says in the comments, the problem maybe with the `.nextDouble&.nextInt()` as it stays in the same line.
you should go to next line to read another number via `.nextLine()` after each `.nextDouble()` and `.nextInt()` event after `.next()` if you use it in the future.

Here a testable example I created for you.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter double");
  while(true){
      System.out.println();
      double s = sc.nextDouble();
      sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter int");
      double i = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Double="+s+", int="+i);
      System.out.println("Wish to cont? 1-Yes, 2-No");
      int j = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      if(j==1) continue;
      else  break;          

 }
```

Comment: I tried running it, entered 3.2 and it gave me input mismatch exception

Comment: also, inputing 3.2 for 2nd number didn't work either, but inputing 3 and 2 worked, and they got printed out as doubles 3.0 and 2.0

Comment: @user2627736  You tried my code, and gave you `InputMismatchException`, em strange, really it's first time to see this.  see the T.C's answer maybe helps